# Help with integration of $\frac{f'(x)}{[f(x)]^n}$.

Tags: integration, derivatives

How do I integrate an expression of the form 
$$
\frac{f'(x)}{[f(x)]^n}
$$
with respect to $x$?

Could I use some kind of recognition method, thus avoiding partial fractions?

For example:
$$
\frac{(2x+1)}{(x^2+x-1)^2}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$S=\int\frac{f'(x)}{f^n(x)}dx=\int\dfrac{d[f(x)]}{f^n(x)\cdot dx}dx=\int f^{-n}(x)\ d[f(x)$$

For $-n+1\ne0\iff n\ne1$

$$S=\frac{f^{-n+1}(x)}{-n+1}+K$$

For $n=1,$

$$S=\int\frac{d[f(x)}{f(x)}=\ln|f(x)|+C$$

Answer (score 0):

Chain rule. You know that
$$\frac{d}{dx}[f(x)]^n = n [f(x)]^{n-1} f'(x).$$

Then $$\int [f(x)]^m f'(x) dx = \frac{[f(x)]^{m+1}}{m+1} + C$$
Just set $m =-n$. For the case $n=1$ you get the logarithm, that is
$$\int \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} dx = \log f(x) + C$$

In Your example the numerator is the derivative of the denominator,  so youcan Write

$$\int (x^2 + x -1)^{-2} (2x+1) dx = \frac{(x^2 + x -1)^{-2+1}}{-2+1} + C = \frac{-1}{x^2 + x -1}+ C$$

Answer (score 0):

Simple, substitute $t=f(x)$:
$$\int\frac{f'(x)}{f^n(x)}=\int\frac{dt}{t^n}=??$$